# Rails routing error Started PATCH "/category/8" No route matches [PATCH] "/8"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, passenger

i get this error in rails production running on passenger. it work fine in development on my localhost. but on server production i get this error when in want to update category

i have some extra route in categories conroller defined with get

route.rb

```
resources :categories
get "categories/:parent_category_id/child_categories", to: "categories#child_categories"
```

categories_controller.rb

```
def edit
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
end
def update
  @category = Category.find(params[:id])
  if @category.update(cat_create_params)
    flash[:success] = "category updated" 
    redirect_to categories_path
  else
    flash[:success] = "updating failed" 
    redirect_to categories_path
  end
end
```

logs are this

```
Started PATCH "/categories/8" for 45.32.150.253 at 2020-02-21 18:38:57 +0330
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [PATCH] "/8"):
```

categories remove by itslef?

and in chrome address bar I see correct url

Comment: try with `/category/8`

Comment: Please show routes.rb, the controller is never hit, so the problem should be somewhere else.

Comment: routes are more than 150 is possible error is in it?
other controllers work fine just some of them doesn't work

Comment: did you try PUT method?

Comment: My guess without seeing the routes file is you have another route overwriting the route you are expecting.

Comment: nothing overwrite it. its happening just in production using passenger.
in local production work well.
i'm sure it's something about passenger

Comment: i check it again and see just update methods not work